# Inline html in Jekyll github-pages

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I have the following in one of the .md files I'm using with a Jekyll website hosted on github pages:

```
<img src="https://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/canopy_orig.jpg" width="32" />&nbsp;[canopy][2] - F#rictionless web testing with Selenium.
```

Both github file preview and stackoverflow interpret that markdown correctly:

[image] [canopy](https://lefthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/) - F#rictionless web testing with Selenium.

But when I published to github-pages I get an email saying there's a Jekyll error. I installed the Jekyll gem and run `jekyll serve` locally to check the error and got this:

```
 ___________________________________________________________________________
| Maruku tells you:
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Could you please format this better?
| I see that "&nbsp;[canopy][2] - F#rictionless web testing with Selenium." is lef
t after the raw HTML.
| At line 150
|   raw_html     |[<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndr1f.jpg" width="32" />][1]&nbsp;[canopy](http://l
efthandedgoat.github.io/canopy/) - F#rictionless web testing with Selenium.|
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Do I have to do anything special to get Jekyll to recognize inline html?

Answer (score 0):

Try and put a space after the non-breakable space `&nbsp;`

```
<img ... width="32" />&nbsp; [canopy](http://lefthandedgoat....) - F#rict....
```

Comment: already tried both that and removing the &nbsp; Putting anything on the same line as the img gives an error, if I put what's after the im on a new line, it works, but then I get a br inserter in the final html